# How to add custom dialog using angular2-mdl?

Tags: angular, material-design-lite, angular2-mdl

I am new to angular2 and im using angular2-mdl for my project. i tried to implement custom dialog given in the http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl/dialogs but i am not to get it work. I am getting errors

Cannot find name 'MdlDialogReference'.
Property 'dialogService' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a simple working example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/HgAvCnzkWAmK1NVxfEUM?p=preview

It's probably the missing `dialogService` property in you 'AppComponent':

```
constructor(private dialogService: MdlDialogService){
}
```